# Select $ in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I noticed that the query

```
SELECT $
```

returns `0`. I am not able to find out why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And what is the main purpose of selecting `$` ? Also could you specify the SQL Server version `SELECT @@Version` ?

Comment: It is interpreted as a monetary constant.

Comment: To add to @GordonLinoff, comment, the T-SQL parser is more lax than it should be. One would expect an explict value to be required for a currency literal rather than a zero default.

Comment: You think that's lax? What about `-$-.`? Tack on all the useless stuff you want... And don't forget about undocumented currency symbols. The end result being that `SELECT -\-.-\-` is not Morse code, but rather a cute way of writing `$0`. Delight friends and colleagues as they puzzle over why `SELECT .1-+\-.-\+-.1` is 0!